# Random Walk: Probability of Hitting to Another State or an Absorbing State Before Returning To the Current State

Tags: probability, martingales

[Random Walk Markov Chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2LO5.jpg)

I have a random walk problem that has n+m states, (1, 2, …, d, …, n, …, n+m).
The agent is currently at the original state 1. For the next move, it has a probability of p1 moving to state 2, and a probability of 1-p1 staying at state 1.

When the agent is at state i (for all i that belong to {2, 3, ..., d-1}), it always has a probability of p1 moving to i+1, a probability of p2 moving back to i-1, and a probability of 1-p1-p2 staying at state i.

When the agent is at state d, its probability to move back to state d-1 is p2. At this state, the agent can diverge to two different routes: One is from state d to state n, and the other is from state d to state n+1 to state n+m. At this state, the agent’s probability of moving to d+1 switches to d2, and his/her probability of moving to n+1 is d1, and probability of staying at state d is 1 – p1 – 2*p2.

For all states i between d+1 and n-1, it always has a probability of p2 moving to i+1, a probability of p1 moving back to i-1, and a probability of 1-p1-p2 staying at state i. For state n, it has a probability of p1 moving back to n-1, and a probability of 1-p1 staying at state n.

The route between state n+1 and state n+m has similar transition probability with the route between state 1 and state d. State n+m is an absorbing state. 
I have uploaded a picture that draws the Markov chain of this random walk problem.

Now, my question is that: if the agent starts at state 2, what is his/her probability of visiting state n before he/she visits state 1 or state n+m.

Comment: You can make all three states $1,n,n+m$ absorbing states.  So then the question amounts to "what is the probability we eventually visit state $n$?" If you define $q_i$ as the probability of eventually visiting state $n$, given we start in state $i$, then $q_1=0$, $q_{n+m}=0$, $q_n=1$, and you can write a recursive relationship between the $q_j$ values for all $j \notin \{0, n, n+m\}$.  Then you obtain the desired value $q_2$.

Comment: Thank you so much.  It is very helpful.  I agree with you. I have tried to write such an equation. Then my challenge is that: I don't know how to solve such a recursive relationship group of equations to get a clean formula for the answer.